# Doing manual joins in CakePHP does not invoke the constructor of the joined model (Virtual Fields needed)

Tags: cakephp, join

I am trying to build a dynamic query through an array of joined tables. These generate dynamic aliases to avoid conflicts (non unique aliases).

However, in my joined tables - I have some virtualFields which are not getting processed. Upon further inspection, it appears that the joined tables `__construct()` functions are not getting called.

Is there a way to get `virtualFields` on a joined table in CakePHP v2.2.8?

Thanks

Comment: Any code that you can share on the queries. In a lot of these edge cases, I tend to trace the code to see what it is actually doing (Cake Book and code don't always agree).

Comment: Oh, and which database driver? DboSource.php shows virtual field processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Manual joins do *not* use your models

Manual joins do not make use of your models. Using manual joins, you are *manually* defining a join and giving it an alias. Although this alias may be the *same* as an existing model, CakePHP will not use your model for the joined tables.

If you need virtualFields, depending on 'what' data is used, you may be able to move the virtualField to the 'main' model you're querying, for example:

```
$this->Foo->virtualFields['foobar'] = 'CONCAT(\'Hello \', Bar.name)';

$foo = $this->Foo->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Foo.name',
            'Foo.foobar',
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'bars',
                'alias' => 'Bar',
                'type'  => 'INNER',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Bar.id = Foo.bar_id',
                )
            )
        ),
        'recursive' => -1
    )
);
debug($foo);
```

Returns;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Foo' => array(
            'title' => 'Foo One',
            'foobar' => 'Hello World'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Foo' => array(
            'title' => 'Foo Two',
            'foobar' => 'Hello Planet'
        )
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you :) this got me where I needed to be!

Comment: @BarryChapman glad I could help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: You rock. Hours of brow beating, beaten. Even go it working on a HABTM relationship... `$this->Site->PaymasterUser->virtualFields['full_name'] = 'CONCAT(UserDetail.first_name, " ", UserDetail.last_name)';
  $paymasterUsers = $this->Site->PaymasterUser->find('list',array(
   'fields' => array('PaymasterUser.id','PaymasterUser.full_name'),`